# elastic beanstalk not creating superuser, invalid syntax

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm just trying to create a super user so that I can log into the admin section of my site. Everything else is working so far.
Here is the relevant portion of my activity error log:

```
[2019-12-22T05:02:06.721Z] INFO  [26175] - [Application update app-191222_070106@18/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_ss_app/Test for Command 02_createsuperuser] : Starting activity...
[2019-12-22T05:02:06.725Z] INFO  [26175] - [Application update app-191222_070106@18/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_ss_app/Test for Command 02_createsuperuser] : Completed activity. Result:

  Completed successfully.
[2019-12-22T05:02:06.726Z] INFO  [26175] - [Application update app-191222_070106@18/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_ss_app/Command 02_createsuperuser] : Starting activity...
[2019-12-22T05:02:07.074Z] INFO  [26175] - [Application update app-191222_070106@18/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_ss_app/Command 02_createsuperuser] : Activity execution failed, because: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/current/app/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 92, in handle
  exec(sys.stdin.read())
  File "<string>", line 1
  from users.models import UserProfile; UserProfile.objects.create_superuser(xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'passxxxword')
  ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)[2019-12-22T05:02:06.721Z] INFO  [26175] - [Application update app-191222_070106@18/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_ss_app/Test for Command 02_createsuperuser] : Starting activity...
[2019-12-22T05:02:06.725Z] INFO  [26175] - [Application update app-191222_070106@18/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_ss_app/Test for Command 02_createsuperuser] : Completed activity. Result:

  Completed successfully.
[2019-12-22T05:02:06.726Z] INFO  [26175] - [Application update app-191222_070106@18/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_ss_app/Command 02_createsuperuser] : Starting activity...
[2019-12-22T05:02:07.074Z] INFO  [26175] - [Application update app-191222_070106@18/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_ss_app/Command 02_createsuperuser] : Activity execution failed, because: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/current/app/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 92, in handle
  exec(sys.stdin.read())
  File "<string>", line 1
  from users.models import UserProfile; UserProfile.objects.create_superuser(xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'passxxxword')
  ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

I'm trying to deploy this through the db-migrate.config file:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_createsuperuser:
    command: "echo \"from users.models import UserProfile; UserProfile.objects.create_superuser(xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'passxxxword')\" | /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py shell"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: studyspot.settings
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're trying to do this via the `shell` management command instead of the `createsuperuser` management command?

Comment: It's a custom user model, I didn't know there was another way because it does require an implementation of create_superuser in managers.py

Comment: As long as `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` are set, you should be fine using `createsuperuser`.

Comment: Isn't the point of the django user model to have all users, including the superuser in the same user table?

Comment: Not following?  `createsuperuser` should create users in your custom user tables as long as settings is set up properly.

Comment: Tried it, now it's worse, my landing page isn't loading.  Getting "Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server."  I do however get the admin login page, but the password is not being accepted, which I set using the environment variable: DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD

Comment: Looks like the admin migration has been applied to the wrong database, 'default', which doesn't even exist in my case.

Comment: createsuperuser doesn't allow you to input the password as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic beanstalk finally took my superuser command in the db-migrate.config file:

```
02_createsuperuser:
command: "echo \"from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.create_superuser('xxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxpasword')\" | python manage.py shell"
```

This was using a custom user model, and there is not much info out there right now on that, so I hope this helps someone.  I didn't include the managers.py file here, but that part should be straightforward, and I did have to make sure to have a save user function in my user creation form in my forms.py file. This took me a week to figure out so I'm posting it to help others.

Comment: Helped myself out again, upgrading the site to Django 4.2.  This command is no longer used in a container command, but in a post deploy hook.  But still works like a charm. Thank you, me!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that this doesn't work you can try the following (works for Django 3.0.6 on a python 3.8.5 environment deployed on AWS EB Linux 2/3.3.1). I use PostgreSQL with this.

This is the full content of the db-migrate.config file that works for me (in 2021).

FIRST TIME DEPLOYMENT:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate && django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true

  02_createsuperuser:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && echo \"from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('ADMIN_NAME', 'EMAIL', 'PASSWORD')\" | python3 manage.py shell"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: ebdjango.settings
```

EVERY OTHER TIME (must change or you'll get errors). Note that the "django-admin.py migrate" is gone:

```
container_commands:
 01_migrate:
     command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate"
        leader_only: true
    
    option_settings:
      aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: ebdjango.settings
```

(Sorry the whites space is a bit off - so just copy paste correct it)

You need to understand that the python environment as deployed on the EC2 instance is actually python2. And the python3 system environment is (I think) 3.6 or 3.7? So you have to activate the python **venv** that you are using as part of your django deployment. That is in /var/app/venv/*/bin/...

You can check by ways of SSH into your EC2 instance and test it there. I think that Python2 is still the default python for most linux machines. Even Ubuntu 18 uses Python2 as the default unless you tell it otherwise. You can simply check the various Python versions. But in any case you have to source the correct environment as is done in the code above. Otherwise this won't work.

Good luck! And hopefully AWS can update their documentation at some point soon.